# CSS overlay some buttons for a footer but keep the rest visible and clickable

Tags: css, overlay

I'm a beginner with CSS and DIVs and am trying to make a button overlay.

At the moment, this footer takes the whole bottom area of the page and covers some of the main area:

[image: screenshot]

This footer area covers half of a button that needs to be clickable.

At the bottom of a page I need to display two Navigation buttons.
This area has a height of 150 pixel and is fixed at the page bottom.

The footer looks like this.

```
<div class="footer">
    <div heigth="100">
        <span heigth="100" width="200" style="float:left; padding-left: 20px">
            <svg id="footer-back" height="200" width="200">
                <use xlink:href="#footerb"/>
            </svg>
        </span>

        <span heigth="100" width="200" style="float:right; padding-right: 40px">
        <svg id="footer-abort" height="200" width="200">
            <use xlink:href="#footera"/>
        </svg>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css for the footer is like this (I included the css for the main area the footer is partially covering and the head which is a fixed area at the top of the page)

```
.header {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}

.main {
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    width: 100%;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: red;
    text-align: left;
}
```

What can I do to make elements from the "main" DIV area show in the footer area below the footer buttons in a way that they are clickable, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working solution is to remove the footer class from the CSS and the div and have the buttons as fixed elements like this.

In my situation the target screen resolution is fixed and known, so I can get away with positioning everything from the left...

```
<div style="background: transparent">
    <span heigth="100" width="200" style="position: fixed; bottom: 40px; left: 10px;">
        <svg id="footer-back" height="200" width="200">
            <use xlink:href="#footerb"/>
        </svg>
    </span>

    <span heigth="100" width="200" style="position: fixed; bottom: 40px; left: 790px;" >
    <svg id="footer-abort" height="200" width="200">
        <use xlink:href="#footera"/>
    </svg>
    </span>
</div>
```